# Prove that a formula $L$ is valid, using the Tableau Method.

Tags: logic

I would like to show that the formula

$((\forall v_0 \forall v_1 \forall v_2 (Rv_0v_1v_2 \to Rv_1v_0v_2) \land (\forall v_0 \forall v_1 \forall v_2 (Rv_0v_1v_2 \to R v_2 v_1 v_0)) \to \forall v_0 \forall v_1 \forall v_2 (R v_0 v_1 v_2 \to R v_0 v_2 v_1 ))$

is valid using the Tableau method, that means I want to show that every path closes for

$((\forall v_0 \forall v_1 \forall v_2 (Rv_0v_1v_2 \to Rv_1v_0v_2) \land (\forall v_0 \forall v_1 \forall v_2 (Rv_0v_1v_2 \to R v_2 v_1 v_0)) \to \forall v_0 \forall v_1 \forall v_2 (R v_0 v_1 v_2 \to R v_0 v_2 v_1 )) : 0$

which is equal to

$((\forall v_0 \forall v_1 \forall v_2 (Rv_0v_1v_2 \to Rv_1v_0v_2) \land (\forall v_0 \forall v_1 \forall v_2 (Rv_0v_1v_2 \to R v_2 v_1 v_0))$ : 1

$\forall v_0 \forall v_1 \forall v_2 (R v_0 v_1 v_2 \to R v_0 v_2 v_1 )$ : 0

Is there a strategy to solve such problem or is it simply trial and error? Everytime I introduced new constants, I end up having an open path, until I got lucky and found one by trial and error, but I doubt this is the correct way of doing it?